# In Symfony2's "The Components -> The PSR-0 Class Loader" section which file(s) is being edited?

Tags: php, symfony, psr-0

I'm trying to grasp how to include a PSR-0 enabled external library on my Symfony2 project.
In "The PSR-0 Class Loader" page (here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/class_loader/class_loader.html").

Which file is being edited? If it's app/autoloader.php, mine looks different than what's being presented:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;
/**
 * @var $loader ClassLoader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
return $loader;
```

Do I have to include this code before return? Or it should be in the other files being called? Still if it's app/autoload.php, shouldn't this code:

```
// register several namespaces at once
$loader->addPrefixes(array(
    'Symfony' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src',
    'Monolog' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/monolog/src',
));
```

be addNamespaces instead? and once I succeed in declaring this library how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, notice that the app/autoload.php file fetches the $loader instance that is returned from vendor/autoload.php. So, the documentation you linked to gives an example where you explicitly create a new instance, but actually, using the app/autoload.php, the instance is ready and waiting for you.

With regards to creating a new library set, let's assume I want to create a new library called 'MyLibrary', and it was going to live in the src directory, after:

`$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

I would declare the following:

`$loader->addPrefix('MyLibrary', __DIR__.'/../src');`

Now I would:

`$ cd src`

`$ mkdir MyLibrary`

`$ mkdir MyLibrary/Component`

`$ mkdir MyLibrary/Component/SomeClasses`

`$ vim MyLibrary/Component/SomeClasses/MyClass.php`

MyClass.php:

```
<?php

    namespace MyLibrary\Component\SomeClasses;

    class MyClass
    {
        ...
    }
```

In another file wanting to use that class, at the top of the file, AFTER the namespace declaration (if there is one):

```
<?php

...

use MyLibrary\Component\SomeClasses\MyClass;

$myClass = new MyClass();
```

However, I have never found a need to do this so explicitly, as I would create a Symfony Bundle, which in effect is a library performing a specific task, and then put your code in the bundle. Creating a bundle is well documented.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. Shed some light in some concepts I was confuse about. But the problem is that I'm not creating the library. I'm incorporating an existing one. And this library has an autoloader class aready developed.  So want I want is to do the Symfony equivalent of the normal php lines require_once '../classes/PHPASN_Autoloader.php';
PHPASN_Autoloader::register();

Comment: So how do I point Symfony to this autoload class ? Should I only point the namespace to the autoload class's dir ?

Comment: This isn't something I have needed to do, so I can only speculate. My first question is whether this library can be downloaded via composer, which would automatically place it in the vendor directly and is globally available within your project. Failing that, you could try importing the library into the vendor directory and place a require_once in your specific php files.

Comment: Well I tried to put the library in a sub folder of the class I'm using it, and then add the lines: require_once 'phpasn1/PHPASN_Autoloader.php';
use PHPASN1\PHPASN_Autoloader; require_once 'phpasn1/PHPASN_Autoloader.php';
use PHPASN1\PHPASN_Autoloader; PHPASN_Autoloader::Autoloader::register('.'); and got a "Parse: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" error.

Comment: Perhaps this has been over complicated, and I apologise.

Suppose you have MyFile.php, and in that file, you want to use the library, try the following in MyFile.php:

<?php

require_once '../classes/PHPASN_Autoloader.php';
PHPASN_Autoloader::register();

// now can use the library in this file
$one = new ASN_Integer(123456);
$two = new ASN_Boolean(true);

Does this simplify things?

Comment: No problem. Actually you're being very helpul. I apologise either, for not knowing how to ask this in a better form. But to answer you, Well yes it simplifies things, but this was the first thing I tried. And it says PHPASN_Autoloader not found.

Comment: Tried this:  require_once 'phpasn1/PHPASN_Autoloader.php'; PHPASN_Autoloader::register(); and this:
 require_once '/phpasn1/PHPASN_Autoloader.php'; PHPASN_Autoloader::register(); and this:
 require_once './phpasn1/PHPASN_Autoloader.php'; PHPASN_Autoloader::register(); and this: 
 require_once 'phpasn1/PHPASN_Autoloader.php'; \PHPASN_Autoloader::register(); and this: 
require_once  __DIR__ . '/phpasn1/PHPASN_Autoloader.php'; \PHPASN_Autoloader::register();
Nothing worked. The PHP_Autoloader file is in a direct sub-folder of the file I'm working named 'phpasn1'.

Comment: The path that you define in the require_once statement is relative from where the current code file is. It currently has an absolute path, as it begins with a /. You mentioned that you have put the library in a subfolder of the class you are using. Therefore, you will need to put that subfolder in the path of your require_once statement. Try:
`require_once 'nameOfSubfolder/phpasn1/classes/PHPASN_Autoloader.php';`

Note there is no / at the beginning.

Comment: If it is in the same directory as the code file you are working in, without a subfolder, you will want:

`require_once 'phpasn1/classes/PHPASN_Autoloader.php';`

Notice `/classes` in the path, as I believe the `PHPASN_Autoloader.php` file is in a `classes` directory.

Comment: Actually, I already had done that. But due to your answers, I noticed that the 'required' line passed ok when I use the format you said. Then I pinpointed the problem to the use class, which I wasn't putting PHPASN1\ prefix before the class. As soon as I did that it worked. will put this to work and futher down the road I will try to grasp how to put this library in Composer format. Thnx very much @Alex. Saved the day.

Comment: Glad the conversation opened your eyes to the problem, good luck with the project